# Valor da variável muda na função principal

Tags: c, funções, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Quando declaro uma função e coloco o parâmetro para receber uma variável do tipo inteiro, por exemplo, dentro da função principal quando eu declaro a função `int param(int x);` e aí eu chamo a função e coloco a variável `x`: `param(x)`, o `x` não retorna o mesmo valor na função principal como retorna na função `int param(int x), por que acontece isso?`

Quando eu deixo a função vazia no parâmetro de entrada, sem receber variável (aliás, falar que não recebe variável está certo?). Nos testes que fiz a função acaba recebendo o valor de x mesmo eu deixando o parâmetro vazio, tipo `int param()`, o valor que a variável `x` retorna na função `param(int x)` é o mesmo valor que a variável `x` na função principal recebe.

O valor de x na função param do código foi alterado, explique porque este
valor foi alterado na função principal.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int x;
int param( ){
   x = x + 10;
   return x;
}
int main(){
   int y;
   printf(“Digite um numero: “);
   scanf(” %d”, &x);
   y = param();
   printf("\nO valor de y e %d \n", y);
   printf("\nO valor de x e %d \n", x);
   system(“pause”);
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Você declarou uma variável global, ou seja, fora de função, ela vale para toda aplicação, então ela é acessada de todo lugar. Isso não é adequado, só funciona bem em exercícios e não deveria fazê-lo, mas já que fez qualquer alteração nela se reflete em todo lugar. O ideal é não ter essa variável, só deve ter variáveis locais e comunicar valores através de parâmetro e retorno de valor.

Este código produz um resultado mais sensato:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int param(int x) {
    return x + 10;
}

int main() {
    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    int x;
    scanf(" %d", &x);
    int y = param(x);
    printf("\nO valor de y e %d \n", y);
    printf("\nO valor de x e %d \n", x);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6OGmEM). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/vzfnharr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/LocalVariable.c).

Agora tem variáveis puramente locais, então mesmo que tenha nomes iguais elas são completamente independentes uma da outra.

Comment: Ah sim, obrigado pela resposta, a questão é para fim didático, da minha faculdade, e eu não estou enxergando o erro, não estou entendendo quando eu deixo o parâmetro vazio, o valor da variável x que é retornado na função int param() ele se comporta como uma variável global, agora quando eu coloco o parâmetro como inteiro x, ou seja, int param(int x), o valor da variável nessa função vale só pra essa função, e não pra função principal, ou seja, não se comporta como uma variável global

Comment: Sim, quando você usa uma variável local, ela não é global.

Comment: Mas por que eu estou usando variável local se a global ainda permanece?

Comment: Porque a local tem prioridade sobre a global, e até por isso não deveria ser usada, é confuso.

Answer (score 0):

No código acima `x` é uma variável de escopo global, isto significa que em qualquer ponto de seu programa que você altere o valor de `x` ele será alterado e o novo valor reconhecido em todo o programa.

Quando você declara:

```
int param(int x){
    x = x + 10;
    return x;
}
```

o parâmetro `x` tem escopo local.
Na realidade na chamada da função o valor da variável utilizada na chamada da função é colocado na pilha e a alteração do valor ocorre na pilha, que é perdida ao final da execução.
Se quiser que a modificação do valor de um parâmetro realizada dentro de uma função seja reconhecida na função chamadora então passe o parâmetro por referência.

============================

Complementando:
Você pode passar o parâmetro por valor ou por referência isto é passar o endereço da variável e tratar adequadamente este parâmetro. Para o exemplo acima:

```
int param(int * x){
    *x = *x + 10;
    return *x;
}
```

e a chamada da função da forma:

```
y =param(&x);
```

Estude sobre escopo de variáveis e também sobre ponteiros para entender melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Mas o que seria exatamente passar o parâmetro por referencia nesse caso? Não estou entendendo quando eu deixo o parâmetro vazio, o valor da variável x que é retornado na função int param() ele se comporta como uma variável global, agora quando eu coloco o parâmetro como inteiro x, ou seja, int param(int x), o valor da variável nessa função vale só pra essa função, e não pra função principal, ou seja, não se comporta como uma variável global, não estou conseguindo entender

Answer (score 0):

A idéia desse exercício era mostrar o efeito do escopo de variáveis e a noção de colisão de nomes. Você pode ter vários `x` ativos em seu programa, e a noção de visibilidade de uma variável --- escopo, *scope* --- é o que se tenta mostrar com seu programa.

Vou reescrever seu programa e tentar explicar. Mas antes vou escrever sobre seu programa

#### seu programa original

Apesar de pequeno seu programa tem vários problemas além do que possa levar à sua dúvida, e abaixo está o original com as linhas numeradas. Seguem algumas notas e quando for o caso o número da linha estará entre `[ ]`.

```
    1   #include<stdio.h>
    2   #include<stdlib.h>
    3   int x;
    4   int param( ){
    5   x = x + 10;
    6   return x;
    7   }
    8   int main(){
    9   int y;
   10   printf("Digite um numero: ");
   11   scanf(" %d", &x);
   12   y = param();
   13   printf("\nO valor de y e %d \n", y);
   14   printf("\nO valor de x e %d \n", x);
   15   system("pause");
   16   }
```

- Use algum alinhamento em seu código. Ajuda você e outros que venham a ler seu programa
- todo programa em C começa por `main()` e se espera ver isso logo no início, em especial se é um programa que não foi você que escreveu. Em geral `main()` fica mesmo em um arquivo a parte, por razões que logo vai aprender.  Use apenas protótipos no início.
- [4] se sua função não recebe parâmetros indique isso ao compilador, declarando `void` como em

```
    int    param(void){
```

- [8] o protótipo de `main()` é

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv);
```

Se não vai usar os parâmetros declare também  `main(void)`

- [11] NUNCA deixe de ler o retorno de `scanf()`. Seu programa lê um único número. Se `scanf()` não ler nada, qual o propósito de seguir com o programa?
- [11] Qual o propósito de ler um valor se nada acrescenta ao seu programa? Só demora mais para testar. Porque não usar algo como     `x = 200;` e seguir adiante? Que diferença faz o valor que o usuário vai digitar se você só vai somar 10 e ver se muda?
- [15] não use `system()`. Não vai estar fazendo nada especial, nem aprendendo nada. system() apenas passa um comando para o *shell*  executar. E é insegura e proibida em muitos círculos.
- [15] Não use `pause` para parar o programa. Se faz isso por causa de algum IDE simplesmente mude para outro que pare o programa sózinho ao rodar na console. Há anos temos vários IDE de qualidade e grátis: mude para um melhor. Não há razão para usar um com uma deficiência tão besta e ter que alterar programas por exemplo antes de entregar, só por esse problema. Se seu instrutor ou escola usar um sistema automático de teste seu programa pode não funcionar direito. E se seu professor rodar o programa num terminal ele vai ficar lá parado no final a toa e não pega bem...
- não teste seus programas apenas dentro do IDE. É um ambiente especial e menos significativo: o código gerado é diferente, o comportamento é diferente. Aprenda a testar na console ou, melhor ainda, no Terminal do Windows, se usa Windows. E com o código de produção, o tal Release code, que é menor e muito mais rápido.

#### O mesmo programa realinhado

seu programa ligeiramente alterado com algumas das coisas que expliquei

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int x;

int param(void);

int main(void)
{
    int y;

    x = 200;
    printf( "\nEm main() x vale %d\n", x);

    y = param();
    printf( "\nDepois de chamar a funcao:\n\n");
    printf("O valor de y e %d \n", y);
    printf("O valor de x e %d \n", x);
}

int param( )
{
    x = x + 10;
    return x;
}
```

A diferença é pequena, mas talvez veja uma maior facilidade para ler o programa.

Uma maneira de rodar, usando uma versão qualquer de gcc em Windows

```
PS C:\chp21-0203-array> gcc -o tst -Wall -std=c17 so0207.c 
PS C:\chp21-0203-array> ./tst

Em main() x vale 200

Depois de chamar a funcao:

O valor de y e 210
O valor de x e 210
```

#### A noção de escopo e um programa mais conveniente para testar

Note que esse programa em C de 3 linhas

```
1
2    int x = 300;
3
```

Compila sem problemas:

```
PS C:\chp21-0203-array> cat p1.c

int  x;

PS C:\chp21-0203-array> gcc -c -Wall -std=c17 p1.c
PS C:\chp21-0203-array>
```

**O que significa?**

Apenas declara uma variável `int` de nome `x` e que pode sim ser usada em outros programas. Ela vale para todo o arquivo p1.c. O fato de não ter mais nada nele é irrelevante para o compilador. Mas se tiver mais código dentro de p1.c essa variável `x`  vai estar definida para todo o arquivo. Se tiver várias funções, tendo ou não `main()` a variável estará definida. Se diz que `x` tem escopo global para p1.c.
No caso de seu programa, `x` existe em `param()` ou em `main()` e em qualquer outro código no arquivo.
Mas se dentro de uma função --- ou mesmo dentro de um loop `for` --- você declarar outro `x` essa variável, esse novo `x` se sobrepõe ao valor declarado inicialmente. Ao retornar da função ou sair do loop esse valor desaparece e volta a ser visível o valor "global" de `x`.

#### um exemplo mais expressivo

Vamos considerar dois arquivos: **p1.c**

```
int  x = 300; // [1]

// fim de p1.c
```

e **so0207.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

extern int x; // [2]

int param(void);
int param2(int);

int main(void)
{
    int x = 223; // novo x em main()! [3]
    int y;

    printf( "\nEm main() x vale %d\n", x);

    y = param();
    printf( "\nDepois de chamar a funcao sem argumentos:\n\n");
    printf("O valor de y e %d \n", y);
    printf("O valor de x e %d \n", x); // [4]

    y = param2(-2345);
    printf( "\nDepois de chamar a segunda funcao com o argumento -2345:\n\n");
    printf("O valor de y e %d \n", y);
    printf("O valor de x e %d \n", x);
}

int param()
{
    x = x + 10; // [5]
    printf( "\nValor de 'x' ao retornar da funcao param(): %d\n", x);
    return x;
}

int param2(int x)
{   // como declarou x ele vai se sobrepor ao valor global
    // o valor de main() e local e nao seria visivel aqui de todo modo
    x = x + 10; // [6]
    printf( "\nValor de 'x' ao retornar da funcao param(int x): %d\n", x);
    return x;
}
```

Compilando e rodando isso:

```
PS C:\chp21-0203-array> gcc -o tst -Wall -std=c17 so0207.c p1.c
PS C:\chp21-0203-array> ./tst
```

A saída, com as linhas numeradas:

```
    1
    2   Em main() x vale 223
    3
    4   Valor de 'x' ao retornar da funcao param(): 310
    5
    6   Depois de chamar a funcao sem argumentos:
    7
    8   O valor de y e 310
    9   O valor de x e 223
   10
   11   Valor de 'x' ao retornar da funcao param(int x): -2335
   12
   13   Depois de chamar a segunda funcao com o argumento -2345:
   14
   15   O valor de y e -2335
   16   O valor de x e 223
```

E porque afinal?

- Na linha 2: em main x vale 223. O valor de x declarado na linha com o comentário `[2]` vem de fora, e vem de p1.c, claro. Vale 300 como está na listagem acima. Mas em main na linha 11 aparece outro `x` com o valor de 223. Esse é o valor vis;ivel em main e o valor anterior desaparece.
- na linha 4: em param o valor de `x` é o valor global, 300 mais o incremento de 10 e é isso que a função retorna para main e assim o valor de `y` é 310. Como o programa saiu de `param()` tudo de `param()` sumiu, e o valor de `x` passa a ser o valor de `x` em main, 223. e isso explica as linhas 8 e 9 da saída.
- ao chamar a versão param2(int) com `param2(-2345)` esse será o valor de x dentro de param2 e assim o valor na linha 11 é -2345 + 10
- E assim ao retornar para main y vale -2335. `x` que nunca foi alterado em main continua claro valendo 223

Usei o `x` em um arquivo diferente apenas para mostrar que mesmo nesse caso o valor está disponível no programa, mas apenas se não for ocultado por qualquer outra variável com o mesmo nome.

Answer (score -1):

Você declarou a variavel x mas só atribuiu um valor a ela na função param()
se quiser exibir o valor de x dentro da função sera assim:
printf("o valor de x e: %d",param());